# I want the bot to send an embed after the reaction it sent has been reacted to

Tags: python, discord.py

So far I've made the bot answer to the command but now I want the bot to reply once somebody has reacted, this is the code I have tried:

```
@client.command()
async def war(ctx): 
    embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='You are starting a war, do you want to continue?', color=0x00000)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojigood)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojibad)
    
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if reaction.emoji == emojigood:
   embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='Please now choose a country', color=0x00000)
   await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: No, my question is not about the variables.

Comment: I refer to your `if` statement. It seems odd. What is `emojigood`?

Comment: I have already made 2 variables emojigood and emojibad, they will show the emoji thumbs up and thumbs down

Comment: What are their values? The result of the `in` operator is a boolean: either `True` or `False`. So it doesn't seem to make sense to compare that to `emojigood`. Did you mean `if reaction.emoji  == emojigood and 'you sure' in message.content:`?

Comment: those were me trying to test something out the if should really be asking, if reaction.emoji==emojigood

Comment: Then I don't follow... Please post a [mre]. If you know your `if` is wrong, why did you post it?

Comment: The problem is my code, what I'm asking is how to make the bot reply with embed after either the thumbs up or down reaction has been clicked, I'm new to python so I don't understand the code so I don't know what is wrong or right, most fo this code is made from tutorials and very little is me, the if code should work but it isn't so I need to figure a different stratergy and that is what my question is.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093402/how-do-i-get-my-bot-to-respond-only-to-reactions-on-a-specific-message-discor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of sample code to explain the bot.wait_for() method using your example, the official docs also have examples and the valid methods and attributes [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

```py
@client.command()
async def war(ctx): 
    embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='You are starting a war, do you want to continue?', color=0x00000)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojigood)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojibad)
    def check(r):
        return (r.emoji == emojigood or r.emoji == emojibad) and r.message == msg
    #Checks whether the message is the same, and the emoji is one of the accepted ones, and returns either True or False
    r = await ctx.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    #this is equivalent to a event listener within your command, it will stop there until a reaction that meets the requirements has been found 
    #(This won't block other commands and functions)
    if r.emoji == emojigood:
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title='War', description='Please now choose a country', color=0x00000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
```

Comment: I tried it with a print statement but it didn't print anything in the terminal when I reacted

Comment: Ah, i just went and checked, if you change "reaction" in the wait_for statement to "reaction_add", i think it should work

Comment: @Therandomcoder also it needs to be single quotes,  i can never remember which things do or dont

Comment: when putting in the command I get this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped

Comment: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Oh, sorry, i didn't know u was required, just change it to check(r, u)